# Filter CSS style by user agent

Tags: css, user-agent

A CSS configuration can filter based on criteria such as @media or other parameters (for example "@media screen and (min-width:1000px)").

My question is: can CSS also filter by user agent? I am thinking of something that would look like this:

@media screen and (user-agent: Safari or whatever).

Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, sounds like a dark pool of junk I don't want to find myself in :) my question comes from the following: I don't want a page to look the same on a non-retina iPhone vs. a retina one. Font sizes, for instance, get all screwed up because of the huge ppi difference. The same will now happen between iPad and iPad mini. And if you look at the android landscape, the situation is even worse. What techniques work for making the end user experience as pleasant as possible on so many different form factors and screen resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use Javascript, you can get the user agent and set the body to have a class with the same name.  Then you can target `body.[user_agent]` in the CSS.